# Sqlite for custom swift framework

Tags: swift, sqlite, frameworks

I am creating a custom swift framework for managing all common data of my applications like data base or common classes.

I import the library "libsqlite3.0.tbd" in Linked Frameworks and Libraries, but when I try to put #import "sqlite3.h" in my Umbrella header file, I recite the next error:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Any idea?
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift and http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift ?

Comment: Finally I used github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift for finish with this problem and it works!

Comment: Damned! I'm amazed by the success of the complex API of SQLite.swift :-) Happy you found your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Step by Step what I did with my sqlite project for it to work, try this (keep the library added and the `#import` statement in the header):

1. First, remove the Header from Build Phases >> Headers.
2. Then go to Build Settings and add the path to the Header in the Objective-C Bridging Header. If you just created the Framework, didn't change the name of the .h file and your project is called Test, for example, the path will be Teste/Test.h (Xcode 7.1.1).

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response, _using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported_, I receive the next error: _using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported_

Comment: Hmm strange. Click in the header that was created with your project. Then, in the File Inspector (first tab of the menu in the right side of the screen) see if there are any target membership selected. If there is any, unselect. In my project there is no item selected there, and when I check any the same error appear.